# How to boost local IIS performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll

My site is developed in ASP.NET.
how can I boot the local IIS performance after rebuilt a library. Here I am using one dll, when I rebuilt the library it is updating a dll.
Now when I refresh a my site it takes 35 secs to load a site.I am using IIS manager 10.0.

IN this dll not more calculation or start up functions. This dll is only used for calculator. Means Addition of two number, percentage and average. No database connection is associated with.

After first time load in next time(second attempt without building dll) it is loaded within 2/3 secs.
so when it is required to build dll it is being a headache.

how can we minimized load time (first time) after dll built?

Comment: Is this really and only the DLL that impacts this massive time laps? Or are you also killing the application pool?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst - no not much.not killing application, it is taking 30 secs after building an DLL, on very first time of this dll load. then after second request it taking normal speed and give output within 1/2 sec.